# Cannot access to mysql in ISPManager-5

Tags: mysql, encryption, sqlite

I changed root password of mysql. Then I cannot access to database from ISPManager-5. ISPManager-5 has not UI for change password(or i don't know). All decision in forums and advanced manuals focused at `/usr/local/ispmgr5/etc/ispmgrnode.db`(sqlite database). I copied this database to my computer and open by SqliteManager and I wished change password. BUT password was crypted. Can some one say  me how can I crypt new password and update this row in database for healthy work my ISPManager-5???

Answer (score 0):

you need to navigate to the "Database servers" module in ISPmanager, and specify a new password there.

If you run ISPmanager Business, navigate to "Cluster nodes" -> "Database server".